# Find the exponential generating function for the number of ways to distribute $r$ distinct objects into five different boxes

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Find the exponential generating function for the number of ways to distribute $r$ distinct objects into five different boxes when $b_1<b_2\le 4$, where $b_1,b_2$ are the numbers of objects in boxes $1$ and $2$, respectively.

I understand that boxes $3, 4$, and $5$ will all just have the fundamental exponential generating function and that their combined generating function will be $e^{3x}$. What I don't understand is the first two boxes with the equality parameter given.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very painstaking approach that may help you to see exactly what’s going on.

The possible values of $b_1$ are $0,1,2$, and $3$, so far starters we try

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6$$

to account for $b_1$. Similarly, the possible values of $b_2$ are $1,2,3$, and $4$, so we try

$$y+\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^3}6+\frac{y^4}{24}$$

to account for $b_2$. I’m using different indeterminates for now, because at this point I still need to keep the $b_1$ and $b_2$ contributions separate.

The product of these polynomials is

$$\begin{align*}
&y+\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^3}6+\frac{y^4}{24}+\\
&xy+\frac{xy^2}2+\frac{xy^3}6+\frac{xy^4}{24}+\\
&\frac{x^2y}2+\frac{x^2y^2}4+\frac{x^2y^3}{12}+\frac{x^2y^4}{48}+\\
&\frac{x^3y}6+\frac{x^3y^2}{12}+\frac{x^3y^3}{36}+\frac{x^3y^4}{144}\;;
\end{align*}$$

however, we don’t want the terms in $x^ky\ell$ with $k\ge\ell$, since they correspond to having $b_1\ge b_2$. After we throw them away, we have

$$y+\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^3}6+\frac{y^4}{24}+\frac{xy^2}2+\frac{xy^3}6+\frac{xy^4}{24}+\frac{x^2y^3}{12}+\frac{x^2y^4}{48}+\frac{x^3y^4}{144}\;.$$

Now replace $y$ by $x$, collect terms, and adjust the denominators to match the exponents to get

$$\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{4x^3}{3!}+\frac{5x^4}{4!}+\frac{15x^5}{5!}+\frac{15x^6}{6!}+\frac{35x^7}{7!}\;,$$

which is the egf for boxes $1$ and $2$ combined. Multiply this by $e^{3x}$, and you’re done.

(And now that I’ve written this, I see that **Markus** has given you the abbreviated version of it.)

Comment: Nonetheless +1 for your answer. I appreciate the  thoughtfully and  helpful explanations you typically provide.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. My reputation score isn't high enough yet for my upvote to show.

Comment: @BrianW: You’re welcome.

Comment: Should you have still included the last term $\frac{x^3y^4}{24}$ when you went through and took away terms with $k\ge\ell$? Also, I don't get how you got your coefficient for $x^6$ in your final line from the line above it. $\frac{1}{24} ≠ \frac{6!}{60}$

Comment: @BrianW: $x^3y^4$ is fine: it has $k=3<4=\ell$. The coefficient of $x^6$ was a mistake: I inadvertently read the x^3y^4$ term as a sixth-degree term and combined it with the previous term. It should be okay now. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Markus: Arrgh! I sure did. Thanks.

Comment: @Markus: See if that looks better; I’m clearly not firing on all cylinders today!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, now it looks perfect! In fact your final result revealed a bug in my calculation which I've corrected now. I like the four eyes principle! :-) Best regards,

Comment: @Markus: Thanks! Yes, they both look good now.

Answer (score 2):

> Three boxes have no restrictions with respect to the objects which results in $e^{3x}$. The restriction $b_1<b_2\leq 4$ of the other objects together with the objects of the three boxes is encoded as
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{3x}&\left(\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)+x\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)\right.\\
> &\quad+\left.\frac{x^2}{2!}\left(\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)
> +\frac{x^3}{3!}\left(\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)\right)\\
> &=e^{3x}\left(\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{4x^3}{3!}+\frac{5x^4}{4!}+
> \frac{15x^5}{5!}+\frac{15x^6}{6!}+\frac{35x^7}{7!}\right)
> \end{align*}

Comment: It looks like you broke it into cases of what box 1 could contain, specifically 0, 1, 2, or 3 objects. From there you took all possible sizes of box 2 given the different sizes of box 1. Is this correct? For example, $(1+x)$ means there is either 0 or 1 object in box one?

Comment: @BrianW: Correct.

Comment: Can you explain why your function has values of $x^7$ and Brian Scott's does not?

Comment: @BrianW: Look at the last term $\frac{x^3y^4}{24}$ in Brians answer. What do you think ...?

Comment: I'm not sure. It makes sense to me for that term to be included on the next line of his solution since $b_2$ is still larger than $b_1$ for that term..

Comment: @Brianw: That's the point. Maybe you'd like to inform Brian about this typo?

Comment: @BrianW: Brian and I, we both have adapted/corrected our answers in the last minutes. Our results are now in sync. Maybe you would like to check the current versions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott and Markus, I checked your final answers to what I came up with doing simple combinatorical arguments and I came up with the answers you now have. Thanks again for your help!